# PHP script to create new csv from another csv after rearranging the data

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv with following structure:
[image]

And I need the output csv as follows:

[image]

That means taking the faetures from each column and put it in the single row.

I am using php office to fetch and write the csv. I have written the following:

```
if ( false === $handle = fopen('../../../3b.csv', 'r') )
    throw new Exception('File open failed.');  
$headers = fgetcsv($handle);
$row =  '';
$row = array();
$data = '';
$data = array();
while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($handle) ) {
    $fields = array_combine($headers, $fields);
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value){
            if($key!='sku'){
                if($value==''){
                    continue;
                }
            }
            $row[$key] = $value;
}
if(sizeof($row)==1){
    unset($row['sku']);
}
    $row = array_filter( $row );
    $data[] = $row;    
}
$data = array_filter($data);
$use_keys = ['sku','AC Rating','color','Feature','Finish','Grade','Installation Location','Installation Method','Plank Style','Size','Specie','Tile Format','Warranty','Wear Layer','Width','LifeStyle',
'Material','Style','Thickness','Appearance','PEIRating','ProtectionRating'];  
foreach($data as $key=>$value){   
    $new_arr = [];
    foreach($use_keys as $apk_item) {  
        $new_value = '';
        if (isset($data[$key][$apk_item])) {
            $new_value = str_replace(",","|",$data[$key][$apk_item]);
        }            
        $new_arr[$apk_item] = $new_value;                
    } 
    $data[$key] = $new_arr;
}
$data = array_filter($data, 'array_filter');
$final_array = array();
foreach ($data as $features) {
    $product = array('feature' => '');
    foreach ($features as $key => $feature) {
        if ($key == 'sku') {
            $product['sku'] = $feature;
        }
        else {

            if($feature!=''){
            $product['feature'] .= $key;
            $product['value'] .= $feature;

            }
        }
    }
   
    $final_array[] = $product;
}
$final_array = array_filter($final_array);  
$table  = '<table border="1" id="csvtable">
<thead><tr><th>sku</th><th>feature</th><th>value</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>';   
foreach($final_array as $value){
    $sku = $value["sku"];
    $combinedfeature = explode(",", $value['feature']);   
            foreach($combinedfeature as $single){   
                $table .=   '<tr><td width="20%">'.$sku.'</td><td width="40%">'.$single['feature'].'</td><td width="40%">'.$single['value'].'</td></tr>';  
            }       
    
 }
 $table .= '</tbody></table>';   
print_r($table);
```

It's giving wrong output. How can I do this? Anyone can help, please?

Comment: If you wanna create another csv, why are you writing html? Just use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: A sample input file would help (and not an image).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more compact method would be to read the input and write out the target file in one loop.

This code reads in each line, combines it with the header and then extracts the sku (and removes it from the details).  Then loops over the remaining details, and if there is a value to output it writes the output to the result file.

As each value may also be a comma separated list, this uses `explode()` to split them into individual items and writes them out as separate parts...

```
$inputFile = "a.csv";
$outputFile = "a1.csv";
$inputHandle = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
$outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
$headers = fgetcsv($inputHandle);
fputcsv($outputHandle, ["sku", "feature", "value" ]);

while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($inputHandle) ) {
    $fields = array_combine($headers, $fields);
    $sku = $fields['sku'];
    unset($fields['sku']);
    foreach ( $fields as $name => $field )  {
        if (!empty(trim($field)))   {
            $subFields = explode(",", $field );
            foreach ( $subFields as $value )    {
                fputcsv($outputHandle, [$sku, $name, $value]);
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose($inputHandle);
fclose($outputHandle);
```

Comment: Hi, Its very close. But i need to explode the values having comma-separated (multiple values of the features)  and put them in rows. Now its showing `117-1002    Feature 
   Square Edge,Unfinished` this would be `117-1002    Feature     Square Edge`
and  `117-1002     Feature    Unfinished` . Can u please update the code. Thanks a million.